# Remove record where first cloumn is non integer

Tags: python, sql

I have dataset in text file which has first column as integer, but some of the record has garbage value in-place of integer, because of that I am not able to load it into db.

So I want to remove record which has first column value non-integer from text file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `grep ^[0-9] dataset > new_dataset`

Comment: `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/ {print;}' dataset > new_dataset`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, can we do it in-place rather than creating new file ?

Comment: @falsetru this would not work for 1.6 as the first value

Comment: Small workaround for "in-place" selection: simply add `; mv new_dataset dataset` to one of the solutions